# Странность в MySQL - пишу цифру "1" в поле (float или Double), а при запросе получаю 0,99!

Tags: mysql

Странность в MySQL. Пишу цифру 1 в поле (Float или Double), а получаю 0,99.
Данные в БД выглядят так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам запрос и результат работы запроса:
(по значению "1", результат не выдаёт - пусто)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Ведь 0,5 ищет и находит. И как эту странность избежать?

Comment: А избежать - вместо `DOUBLE` использовать `NUMERIC(2,1)`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Большое спасибо. В MySQL я самоучка, а в Delphi такого недочёта я не замечал.

Comment: Повезло/не повезло. Этот алгоритм присутствует везде. В том же Delphi, есть тип `Currency` для хранения точных значений и функция `Math.SameValue()` для сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой